# Using GridLayout in android, how can I set it up so each item i add is placed correctly (unlimited number)?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to set up a simple grid layout that will place a thumbnail with a comment below it in a 2 column and infinite row table(see pic below)

[image: GridLayout i'm trying to make dynamic]

Whenever a picture is taken it is added to the grid layout but all the parameters I've tried either gives me an error after the 3rd picture or just displays incorrectly.

{CODE}

This part of my code creates a thumbnail with size 400,400 from an image just taken and then is added to the gridlayout view along with the gridlayout parameters.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //setups
    setResult(resultCode);
    GridLayout templayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.pictureLayout);

    int col = 2;
    int row = 2;
    templayout.setColumnCount(col);
    templayout.setRowCount(row);
    String path = tempPicture[4]; 

    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap thumb = createThumbnailFromBitmap(path, 400, 400);
    image.setImageBitmap(thumb);
    image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(400,400));


    GridLayout.Spec rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
    GridLayout.Spec colSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 2);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpan, colSpan);
        templayout.addView(image, gridParam);
        temp = Integer.valueOf(tempPicture[0]);
        image.setId(temp);
        image.setTransitionName(path);
        image.setOnClickListener(ClickPic(image));
        addToTempList(tempPicture);
//This creates a edit text just below the newly created thumbnail
        createEditableComment(tempPicture[0], templayout);
        }
```

The createComment method, just gets added to below the thumbnail after creation (sometimes below)

```
void createEditableComment(String picId, GridLayout belowpic){
    EditText comment = new EditText(this);
    comment.setTextSize(20);
    comment.setId(Integer.valueOf(picId));
    comment.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    pictureComments.add(comment);
    belowpic.addView(comment);

}
```

Here's my xml just cause. Cheers

```
        <GridLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/pictureLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2">
        </GridLayout>
```

Comment: You quesition is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/pictureLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

Comment: I see, that's the perfect view im looking for however, on hte programming side i can't seem to simply add item to grid, is there anyway around creating the whole adapter and just create a fixed gridview that items can be added to?

Comment: You can add items to gridview. For that you need to define a xml layout for one item then make a adapter class and inflate that xml layout to your gridview.

Comment: if you are not not clear how to use adapter with gridview then let me know i will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks yeah, I actually just start making an adapter now and plan to pass in the image and comments, thanks for your support!

Comment: If this answer helped you to understand then kindly mark this as answer.

Comment: I did but it's not as simple as using xml, i did mark it but it needed more information